# a question about an understanding of 'if' statenent

Tags: c

```
if (!strcmp(book->title, target) || !strcmp(book->author, target))
```

This is the sentence. I know what it means.I change it in another way.

```
if (strcmp(book->title, target) || strcmp(book->author, target))
```

Just delete two '!' . 
My understanding: I just need to get if(1) and then the if statement can go on.
We know that if book->title is euqual to target or book->author is  equal to target and then it will return 0. I presume book->author is equal to target. It will return 0. At the same time, strcmp(book->title, target) will return a number which is not 0. So if statement can go on too.
  But it is not the fact.

Comment: First statement says either title or author match target. Second says if either title or author does NOT match target.

Comment: You have two integers and four comparisons; which is the “it” you keep referring to?

Comment: the thing that is confusing you is that strcmp returns 0 if the string is equal, 0 is logically false, hence the need for the !. Or you could say 'strcmp....==0'

Comment: @  David C. Rankin I know what you mean. But on the second statement, we presume that book->title == target and then it is equivalent to if( 0 || x) and x != 0 . So I think the result is if(1). The 'if statement ' can go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me simplify your example:

```
if (!strcmp("Moby Dick", target) || !strcmp("Melville", target))
```

This will succeed and pass if `target` is *either* one of the two strings, `"Moby Dick"` or `"Melville"`.  If the target string is something else entirely, say `"Dickens"`, it will fail.

---

Now, your attempt to simplify it is:

```
if (strcmp("Moby Dick", target) || strcmp("Melville", target))
```

If `target` is `"Moby Dick"`, the first expression will be `0`, and the second expression will be `1`, so the combined expression will be TRUE (because `0 || 1` --> True).

If the `target` is something else entirely, like `"Dickens"`, then ***both*** parts of the expression will be TRUE.  And `1 || 1` --> TRUE.   So the expression will be TRUE, no matter what the target is!

Answer (score 2):

`||` means OR => in this case if either one of the conditions is True then the code will get executed.

`&&` stands for AND -> both need to be True for the code to get executed.

`!` stands for negate. If you have !True this is equivalent to False

Comment: Add to that `strcmp` tests true as a negative (returns `0` when strings match) and you add one more layer of negation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, very true.

Comment: `strcmp` returns an integer, not True nor False.

Comment: Of course... 0/strings match, !0/strings don't match. Just as C defines `false` and `true` in `stdbool.h`

Comment: integers that are non-zero evaluate to True

Comment: I know what you mean. But on the second statement,  if we presume that book->title == target and then it is equivalent to if( 0 || x) and x != 0 . So I think the result is if(1). The 'if statement ' can go on.  This is my thought . I don't know where is  wrong.

Comment: if(1) means that the statement inside the conditional block will be executed.